# how to send command line arguments to a process through udev?

Tags: usb, udev

On detection of a USB device I'm trying to have udev start up a process and pass the serial number of the USB device as an argument to the process.

file:/etc/udev/rules.d/10-FTDI2232H-usb.rules

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6010", RUN+="/opt/usbprog %s" ATTR{serial}

I'm not to sure if the printf style arguments is how this supposed to be accomplished.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah...I finally figured it out.

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6010", RUN+="/opt/usbprog %s{serial}", $ATTR{serial}